# For all sets A, B, and C, prove or disprove conditional...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For all sets A, B and C, if $(A \cap B) \cup C \subseteq A \cap (B \cup C) $, then $ C - (A \cup B) = \phi $.

I know this statement is true, as the antecedent implies that there is no element in C that is not also an element of A or B.

Furthermore, we can assume A, B, and C are sets and that $(A \cap B) \cup C \subseteq A \cap (B \cup C) $.

I believe we can prove this statement by contradiction, that is, by supposing $ C - (A \cup B) \ne \phi $ and showing how that leads to $(A \cap B) \cup C \not\subseteq A \cap (B \cup C) $, which would contradict our previous assumption that $(A \cap B) \cup C \subseteq A \cap (B \cup C) $.

...buuut I've been having trouble with the nitty gritty of the proof-by-contradiction. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing by contradiction as you have started:

So, suppose $C\setminus (A\cup B)\neq \emptyset$.

So, we have some $c$ such that $c\in C$ while $c\notin A$ and $c\notin B$.

Since $c\in C$ we have $c\in (A\cap B)\cup C$.

But, since $c\notin A$ we have that $c\notin A\cap (B\cup C)$, contradicting that $(A\cap B)\cup C$ should be a subset of $A\cap (B\cup C)$.